# VPN only working for some users

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have setup a VPN for my office. The configuration is as follows:

- Installing **OpenVPN** server on one of the office servers (**Ubuntu** 20.04 server) using port **1194** and protocol **UDP**.
- The port is **forwarded** to the outside through the modem/router (along with other ports like 443, 80, 3000, 8000 that we use for other services)
- I selected the **IP range of 10.8.x.x** as the IPs for the VPN users.
- For each client that I want to connect, I generated an `ovpn` file using the same script I used to install OpenVPN server.

The number of **clients** I have is around **10/15 at max**.

The setup can be better understood looking at this **diagram**:

[image: VPN Diagram]

When some clients and I connect to the VPN everything works fine: Internet connection, the public IP is the one of the office, I can connect with SSH and other protocols to the servers inside of the office and I can also connect with the other clients using their 10.8.x.x IPs.

Many other clients though can connect to the VPN but they can only use the internet and connect to other clients with IPs 10.8.x.x. They **cannot connect to the internal machines** at IPs 192.168.1.x in any way.

I cannot understand why:

- The clients affected by the problem have a variety of OSs and do not share a single trait that could be the culprit. (I have the exact same computer with same OS version and same version of OpenVPN client, but I work just fine)
- I checked and each of the clients gets a different IP like 10.8.0.x so there are no conflicts there.

What can I test to find the solution?
Did I configure the VPN in a wrong way?

Comment: Do they share the trait of...using 192.168.1.x for their local networks? A local /24 route will always have priority over the /0 default route that your VPN provides.

Comment: @user1686 You mean if they have IPs like 192.168.1.x in their home networks? If so I think yes. A great majority of home networks have that range of IPs. So do I have to change the IPs of the machines in my office so that they have a low probability of conflicting with home networks?

Comment: Or maybe use `NETMAP` in `iptables`.

Comment: @TomYan could you elaborate. I am not an expert (as you might have guessed from the simple architecture and noob question) so I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the IP configuration on your LAN hosts, you can "allocate" another subnet from e.g. the `10.0.0.0/8` block, such as `10.1.0.0/24`, to "represent" `192.168.1.0/24` on the VPN clients.

Add this to your OpenVPN server conf:

```
push "route 10.1.0.0 255.255.255.0"
```

So that the VPN clients will route traffics for `10.1.0.0/24` into the tunnel. (If your setup does not make use of push-pull, `route 10.1.0.0 255.255.255.0` will need to be added to each client conf.)

Then add a `NETMAP` rule in the `PREROUTING` chain of the `nat` table to, so/such that destination NAT will be performed on the traffics in concern:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.1.0.0/24 -j NETMAP --to 192.168.1.0/24
```

The destination IP of the traffics will be changed from `10.1.0.x` to `192.168.1.x` for each IP in the `10.1.0.0/24` subnet / block before being forwarded to the LAN hosts in the office.

Source IP of the replies from the LAN hosts will also be "reverse NAT'd" when they are forwarded to the VPN clients. But if (and only if) you expect the LAN hosts to be able to "actively" reach the VPN clients, you will need to add the following `NETMAP` rule as well:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j NETMAP --to 10.1.0.0/24
```

Otherwise the replies from the VPN clients will go to their own LAN hosts (if exist).

Obviously with this approach, the caveat would be that the VPN clients will be accessing the office LAN hosts with IPs of a different "prefix" (`10.1.0` instead of `192.168.1`). And naturally, some corner-case issues (that I'm not familiar with / do not have exact examples) that come with any NATing might occur as well.

Comment: This looks too complicated for me. Sorry... I think that with my knowledge I could maybe setup the office LAN to use a different block of IPs. That's as far as I can go.

Thank you anyway. I understood the problem and I understand that your solution would be optimal so I will mark it as accepted.